# C# clock not working cause there is no negative coordinates in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a simple clock and it isn't working because sin and cos give negative values which wpf doesnt have!

```
namespace Desenho
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        public static extern void AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    public static extern void FreeConsole();

    private Timer timer1;
    int i = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AllocConsole();
        Console.Clear();
        InitTimer();

    }

    public void InitTimer()
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1; // in miliseconds
        timer1.Start();
        /*for(int a = 0; a>-200; a--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Angulo: {0}; Cos: {1}; Sen: {2}; Rad: {3};", a, Math.Cos(toRad(a)), Math.Sin(toRad(a)), toRad(a));
        }*/
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*if(i == 5)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
        mudaCores(i);
        i++;*/
        float x = 100+(float)Math.Cos(toRad(i));
        float y = 100+(float)Math.Sin(toRad(i));
        desenhaLinha(x, y);
        i--;
        Console.WriteLine("Angulo: {0}; X: {1}; Y: {2};", i, x, y);
    }

    private async void desenhaLinha(float x, float y)
    {

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                    panel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => panel.linhas.Add(new Cordenadas(new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 2), new Point(100, 100), new Point(x, y)))));
                    panel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => panel.InvalidateVisual()));

            });

        }



    private async void mudaCores(int i)
    {
        Color[] cores = new Color[] { Colors.Red, Colors.Black, Colors.Blue, Colors.Green, Colors.Yellow, Colors.Violet };
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { panel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => panel.color = cores[i]));
                panel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => panel.InvalidateVisual()));
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    double toRad(double graus)
    {
        double rad;
        rad = graus * Math.PI / 180;
        return rad;
    }
}
```

}

My drawLine func only takes one point as argument cause it assumes the center one as 100, 100. How can i make this work?

Comment: Um, add 100 to each coordinate so that that's the centre?

Comment: Make what work? You would *at least* have to show us your drawLine method. Besides that, a RotateTransform in the Transform property of a LineGeometry might be much more appropriate than what you have now.

Comment: Tried to add 100, didnt work :/

Comment: Just posted all the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you should throw away all your code and write a MVVM application with separation between view and view model.

First create a view model for your clock, e.g. with three angle properties for the hour, minute and second hand of your clock, and a DispatcherTimer that updates these properties from the current time (`DateTime.Now`) in the UI thread.

```
public class ClockViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ClockViewModel()
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
        timer.Tick += TimerTick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var t = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        HoursAngle = t.TotalHours * 30 % 360; // fractional hours
        MinutesAngle = t.Minutes * 6; // full minutes
        SecondsAngle = t.Seconds * 6; // full seconds
    }

    private double hoursAngle;
    public double HoursAngle
    {
        get { return hoursAngle; }
        set
        {
            hoursAngle = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(HoursAngle)));
        }
    }

    private double minutesAngle;
    public double MinutesAngle
    {
        get { return minutesAngle; }
        set
        {
            minutesAngle = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MinutesAngle)));
        }
    }

    private double secondsAngle;
    public double SecondsAngle
    {
        get { return secondsAngle; }
        set
        {
            secondsAngle = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SecondsAngle)));
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a view with three Lines for the clock hands, each of which has a `RotateTransform` with a data-bound `Angle` property. The view shown below puts the clock in the upper left corner of the bottom right cell of a 2xx Grid, in order to center the Lines in the Grid.

The `DataContext` of the Window is set to an instance of the view model.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ClockViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Line Y2="-50"
              Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="9"
              StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Triangle">
            <Line.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding HoursAngle}"/>
            </Line.RenderTransform>
        </Line>
        <Line Y2="-100"
              Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="7"
              StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Triangle">
            <Line.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding MinutesAngle}"/>
            </Line.RenderTransform>
        </Line>
        <Line Y2="-100"
              Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3"
              StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Triangle">
            <Line.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding SecondsAngle}"/>
            </Line.RenderTransform>
        </Line>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```